# How can I get the file version information on windows using NodeJS

Tags: windows, node.js, filesystems

I'd like to create a routine to check the file version details on a windows server. Is there a NodeJS module for providing file version information?

For clarity the details include:

```
Company Name
Copyright Notice
Product Name
Product Description
File Version
Product Version
```

Comment: I have no idea what "file version details" means

Comment: @TravisWebb it is a standard windows convention for EXE's and DLL's. Usually the information found on the properties view of a file. Installation software often utilise this information for know if a components needs to be updated or not.

Comment: I've never seen "Company Name" be part of a file descriptor, but I also haven't used Windows in 10 years. I would look in here to see if any of those do what you want: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html. Otherwise, search npm.

Answer (score 0):

The [win-version-info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/win-version-info) module does exactly this.

*Example Code from their docs* - 
`example.js`

```
const vi = require('win-version-info')
console.log(vi(process.argv[2]))
```

`output`

```sh
> node example "C:\Program Files (x86)\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe"
{ FileVersion: '46.0.0.5903',
  LegalCopyright: '©Firefox and Mozilla Developers; available under the MPL 2 license.',
  CompanyName: 'Mozilla Corporation',
  FileDescription: 'FirefoxDeveloperEdition',
  ProductVersion: '46.0a2',
  InternalName: 'FirefoxDeveloperEdition',
  LegalTrademarks: 'Firefox is a Trademark of The Mozilla Foundation.',
  OriginalFilename: 'firefox.exe',
  ProductName: 'FirefoxDeveloperEdition',
  BuildID: '20160229004006' }
```